# Changing function argument on each function call

Tags: javascript, scope, parameter-passing, function-call

Want to pass an argument into my function (a number - zero), and each time my function is called I want to increase this argument by one (so that it would be arg = 0 then arg = 1 then arg = 2 and so on).

However, of course, each time I increase it locally in my function, it's then reset back to zero globally.

Cannot think of any (simple) solution, here's my simplified code...

```js
var arg = 0
function test(arg) {
    arg += 1;
    console.log(arg)
}

test(arg);
test(arg);
```

Comment: because you make a local variable arg... Not sure about your use case to offer a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take an object, because this is hadec over by reference and increment a property of it. Primitive values, like a number value are handed over by value.

```js
function test(arg) {
    ++arg.value;
    console.log(arg.value);
}

var arg = { value: 0 };

test(arg);
test(arg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sans the clean up of the variable names for readability, this should work based on what you have in the question.

```
var arg = 0;

function test(arg) {
   arg += 1;
   console.log(arg);
   return arg
}

arg = test(arg);
arg = test(arg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other commenters said, JS is call by value, so you won't be editing that local variable.  There are a few other options, such as the following

```
var arg = 0;
function test() {
  arg = arg + 1;
  return arg;
}
console.log(test())); // Would output 1
console.log(arg); // Would also output 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because generators are hip, here's a generator version:

```
function* increaseByOne(i) {
    while (true) {
        i++;
        yield i;
    }
}

var gen = increaseByOne(0);

console.log(gen.next().value); //1

console.log(gen.next().value); //2

console.log(gen.next().value); //3

console.log(gen.next().value); //4
```